# Not able to deploy shared dashboard using terraform into pre-prod but working in all other environments

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-template-file, azure-dashboard

Azure shared dashboard is being deployed using Terraform. It is working fine in all other environments except in one environment. Below is the error message.

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/1.0.11/x64/terraform apply -auto-approve /home/vsts/work/1/tfplan-pre-1/tfplan-pre
azurerm_dashboard.custom-dashboard: Creating...
azurerm_dashboard.custom-dashboard: Creating...
|
|
##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/1.0.11/x64/terraform' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Terraform Apply
```

We are not getting any error message. terraform apply simply stops right after message "azurerm_dashboard.custom-dashboard: Creating...". The same is working fine in all other environments and failing in this environment. Is there any other way that can be used to get more info on this issue

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: It looks like `terraform apply` is failing, but the actual failure message doesn't seem to be in your posted code -- instead, we're seeing the error message from whatever tool is running it for you. You will need to get the actual error that TF is running into during the apply.

Comment: You don't need the `-auto-approve` when using the plan file: https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/apply#saved-plan-mode

Comment: We are not getting any error message. terraform apply simply stops right after message "azurerm_dashboard.custom-dashboard: Creating...". The same is working fine in all other environments and failing in this environment. Is there any other way that can be used to get more info on this issue